# Vectorized element-wise division on Sparse Matrices in R

Tags: r, vectorization, sparse-matrix

A/B in R performs an element-wise division on the matrix.

However, if I generate a sparse matrix from the Matrix package, and try to divide A/B, I get this error:

```
> class(N)
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
> N/N
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
>
```

Interesting. When the sparse matrix is small in total size, I get this behavior:

```
> m <- sparseMatrix(i=c(1,2,1,3), j=c(1,1,3,3), x=c(1,2,1,4))
> m/m
3 x 3 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  NaN    1
[2,]    1  NaN  NaN
[3,]  NaN  NaN    1
>
```

But when it's moderately sized (~ 20000 elements), I get the Cholmod error.

Is there a workaround or a more proper way to do element-wise division on sparse matrices in R?

Comment: Ah; works for regular arrays, but not sparse arrays; I'll update the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with element-wise division is that if your matrices are both sparse, then you'll have a lot of `Inf` and `NaN` in the result, and these make it dense. That's why you get the out-of-memory errors.

If you want to replace `Inf` and `NaN` with zeros in the result, then the solution is relatively easy, you just get the `summary()` of both matrices and work with the indices and values directly.

You'll need to restrict the `A` and `B` index vectors to their intersection and perform the division on that. To get the intersection of index pairs, one can use `merge()`.

Here is a quick and dirty implementation:

```
# Some example data
A <- sparseMatrix(i=c(1,1,2,3), j=c(1,3,1,3), x=c(1,1,2,3))
B <- sparseMatrix(i=c(3,2,1), j=c(3,2,1), x=c(3,2,1))

sdiv <- function(X, Y, names=dimnames(X)) {
  sX <- summary(X)
  sY <- summary(Y)
  sRes <- merge(sX, sY, by=c("i", "j"))
  sparseMatrix(i=sRes[,1], j=sRes[,2], x=sRes[,3]/sRes[,4],
               dimnames=names)
}

sdiv(A, B)
# 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#           
# [1,] 1 . .
# [2,] . . .
# [3,] . . 1
```

Thanks to flodel for the suggestion about using `summary` and `merge`.

Comment: +1 - but this could be a lot shorter if you used `summary` and `merge`

Comment: @flodel: indeed, I forgot about `summary`, that is the right solution, and no direct access to the internals is needed. Thanks.

Comment: I hit an edge case with this: if the last row or column of the matrix are empty, then the initial `sparseMatrix` will contract, and then applying the `dimnames` will lead to a size mismatch. To make this more robust, the `dims` should also be defined (e.g., with a `dims=dim(X)` argument).